# How to run the application background in iOS like service in Android?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am newbie to iPhone development.

1. Is there any API or method to run the application in background?
2. How to check which application is running in foreground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant check which app is currently in the front. You are only notified when your app gets sent to the background or when it is brought up again. You can however receive certain events while your app is in the background, so you can still do some work if needed.

Comment: Thank you, Can you provide some sample code to check which app is in front, What kind of events i can receive while my application is running in background.

Answer (score 2):

In short: no. iOS multitasking is much more limited than Android's. There are more details in Apple's documentation.